Cannt create a tenant of minio with network error
I deployed minio via kubernetes but some error for the minio when i create a tenant.
I checked the logs, it seems like this
INFO: Unable to use the drive http://storage-pool-0-0.storage-hl.minio.svc.cluster.local:9000/export: drive not found, will be retried
INFO: Unable to use the drive http://storage-pool-0-1.storage-hl.minio.svc.cluster.local:9000/export: drive not found, will be retried
INFO: Unable to use the drive http://storage-pool-0-2.storage-hl.minio.svc.cluster.local:9000/export: drive not found, will be retried
INFO: Unable to use the drive http://storage-pool-0-3.storage-hl.minio.svc.cluster.local:9000/export: drive not found, will be retried
INFO: Waiting for a minimum of 2 drives to come online (elapsed 23m13s)

All logs is this, and i try to execuate kubectl exec -it storage-pool-0-3 -n minio -- curl -I http://storage-pool-0-0.storage-hl.minio.svc.cluster.local:9000.
I got such as
Defaulted container "minio" out of: minio, sidecar, validate-arguments (init)
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 225
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: MinIO
Vary: Origin
Date: Sun, 21 Jul 2024 23:13:57 GMT

What should i do to fix that problem to use minio normally?
My kubernetes status is
root@dev-master-1:~/minio/mc# kubectl get all -n minio
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/storage-pool-0-0   2/2     Running   0          32m
pod/storage-pool-0-1   2/2     Running   0          32m
pod/storage-pool-0-2   2/2     Running   0          32m
pod/storage-pool-0-3   2/2     Running   0          32m

NAME                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
service/minio             LoadBalancer   10.101.4.180    192.168.3.240   80:32676/TCP     32m
service/storage-console   LoadBalancer   10.103.42.214   192.168.3.241   9090:31544/TCP   32m
service/storage-hl        ClusterIP      None            <none>          9000/TCP         32m

NAME                              READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/storage-pool-0   4/4     32m

And my cni is cilium, LoadBalance is Metallb
